# What are the differences between a deep belief network, a restricted Boltzmann machine and a deep Boltzmann machine?

Tags: comparison, boltzmann-machine, deep-belief-network, restricted-boltzmann-machine, deep-boltzmann-machine

Can anyone list the differences between deep Belief network (DBN), restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM), deep Boltzmann machine (DBM) using simple examples?

Links to other resources are also appreciated.

Comment: There's already a question about the difference between DBN and DBM ([https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/130/2444](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/130/2444)) and the difference between stacked DBN and DBM ([https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2583/2444](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2583/2444)).